# Class member to point to a specific node member of an STL list?

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, compiler-errors, linked-list

How can I store a pointer to the name of a person's spouse as a private member of the person's class?

For example, say I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class person
{
    private:
        string name;
        string *spouse;

    public:
        void setName(string tempName) { name = tempName; }
        void setSpouse(string &tempSpouse) { spouse = &tempSpouse; } // ERROR HERE?

        string getName() { return name; }
        string getSpouse() { return spouse; } // ERROR HERE?
};

int main()
{
    person entry;
    list<person> personList;
    list<person>::iterator itr1, itr2;

    /* Adding two people/nodes to the linked list. */

    entry.setName("John Doe");

    personList.push_back(entry);

    entry.setName("Tina Doe");

    personList.push_back(entry);

    /* Attempting to assign Tina Doe as John Doe's spouse. */

    for (itr1 = personList.begin(); itr1 != personList.end(); itr1++)
    {
        if (itr1->getName() == "John Doe")
        {
            for (itr2 = personList.begin(); itr2 != personList.end(); itr2++)
            {
                if (itr2->getName() == "Tina Doe")
                {
                    itr1->setSpouse(itr2->getName()); // ERROR HERE?
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /* Displaying all Names with Spouses afterwards. */

    for (itr1 = personList.begin(); itr1 != personList.end(); itr1++)
    {
        cout << "Name: " << itr1->getName() << " | Spouse: " << itr1->getSpouse() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am unable to assign the address of the spouses name to the pointer member in the class. I've noted in the comments where I believe the errors might be.

You can view the code and errors here: https://ideone.com/4CXFnt

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If there is any other information that I neglected to provide, please let me know, and I will edit this post immediately. Thank you.

Comment: Consider replacing [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) with [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) is a doubly-linked list, and you shall be using it only then really necessary (frequent insertions and deletions in the middle). For any other usages, it is slow. By default, use `vector`.

Comment: @IlyaPopov Unfortunately, for this particular program, using a vector is out of the question. It must be a linked list, and the spouse member must contain a pointer to the spouse's name record.

Comment: Ah, I see. If it must contain a pointer to spouse, then indeed a list is a suitable choice.

Comment: @IlyaPopov Do you have any other suggestions on how to solve the errors I am getting with my code?

Comment: Shouldn't `spouse` member be a pointer to `person` rather than pointer to `string` then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getName` returns a temporary `std::string` (copy of the `name` variable), and the compiler is trying to save you from referencing a part of memory that will be soon deleted. This error has nothing to do with lists - to fix it you need to either store copies in `spouse` variable (which will result in storing same data in multiple places) or return a reference in `getName`. You can also consider creating another accessor (private one), but it's ugly.

I'd recommend storing copies, but if references/pointes are really required then it's sufficient to modify lines:

```
    string getName() { return name; }
    string getSpouse() { return spouse; } // ERROR HERE?
```

to

```
    string& getName() { return name; }
    string getSpouse() { return *spouse; } // ERROR HERE?
```

however, for consistency I'd recommend:

```
    string& getName() { return name; }
    string& getSpouse() { return *spouse; } // ERROR HERE?
```

Comment: Can you give me a code example of your answer? In this particular case, the spouse member must contain a pointer to the spouse's name record.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you.

Comment: This is great but does not fix the `itr1->setSpouse(itr2->getName());` (or I don't understand something)

Comment: @styko: it actually does - since `get` methods return a reference now, and `set` take a reference, a reference to actual `spouse` is taken - thus no compilation error. I'm not trying to claim that this is a good way to solve this problem - I'm simply stating that it works they way it's expected. I tend to agree though that probably a `person` pointer would be expected there instead of `string`

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems. The first is easy to fix: `getSpouse` doesn't return the right type. You should write

```
string getSpouse() { return *spouse; } // Derefencing the pointer and returning a string
// or
string* getSpouse() { return spouse; } // Returning the pointer
```

The second problem is more subtle. When you write: `itr2->getName()` , you only have a value (a **copy** of itr2->name): you do not store a variable that you will be able to change, so you cannot make a reference to it.

There is no easy way you can have a pointer in a class instance pointing the a private variable of another instance. I guess you should question the way you are doing things and create a pointer to the `person` and not to the name (remember pointer are cheap, they are just memory locations).

```
class person
{
    private:
        string name;
        person *spouse;

    public:
        void setSpouse(person *_spouse) { spouse = _spouse; }
        person* getSpouse() { return spouse; } 
        string getSpouseName() { return spouse->getName(); }
};
```

This work, but still it is not safe: if `spouse` is destroyed and try to access it from `person`, you will run into deep problems… (note that you had the same problem with the `string`).

So what is the fix? Well, if you only want `B` to be the spouse of `A`, you can create `B` first and make a reference in `A` with a constructor. But if you want `B` to be the spouse of `A` and `A` the spouse of `B`, you have to use either the unsafe trick above and be careful, or stock the spouses' list outside the class.